# How do you split an array into specific intervals in Num.py for Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, concatenation

The question follows a such:

x = np.arange(100)

Write Python code to split the following array at these intervals: 10, 25, 45, 75, 95

I have used the split function and unable to get at these specific intervals, can anyone enlighten me on another method or am i doing it wrongly?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of describing what you've tried, it is better to attach your script in your question, with the result, and the error if there's any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's both the manual way and the numpy way with split.

```python
# Manual method
x = np.arange(100)
split_indices = [10, 25, 45, 75, 95]

split_arrays = []
for i, j in zip([0]+split_indices[:-1], split_indices):
    split_arrays.append(x[i:j])

print(split_arrays)

# Numpy method
split_arrays_np = np.split(x, split_indices)
print(split_arrays_np)
```

And the result is (for both)

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), 
 array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]), 
 array([25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]), 
 array([45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74]),
 array([75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94])
]
```